# Really puzzled by question closure

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

A question I asked last week ([programmatically edit an image to get what background-blend-mode: luminosity does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765253/programmatically-edit-an-image-to-get-what-background-blend-mode-luminosity-doe)) was closed as "unclear". I really think it is clear, and surely clear enough for those who know how to answer...

Can you please tell me what you consider unclear? I edited it to be even clearer but no one seems to react.

It's not even a very strange question so I really cannot understand. I personally consider very impolite this way of doing.

A comment would have been much more correct as a first action.

Comment: Seems clear to me. OP wants to apply some `CanvasRenderingContext2D` methods or some `ImageData` manipulation to produce the same result as CSS would. What happens later with the `ImageData` doesn’t seem relevant (e.g. saving it somewhere). Still, the question would be better with _some_ attempt.

Comment: You've stated your requirements, but it is unclear what your problem is. If you compare your question to open upvoted questions, you'll notice that those questions state, as you did, 1) what you are trying to do, but they also state 2) what they tried 3) what the result was and 4) why that didn't work for them. If you haven't got #2 because you didn't do #3, that's a problem. You're expected to do some research and try to get it working before asking for help. Otherwise, you should look at finding a contractor.

Comment: Biggest thing to remember: we can't read your mind.  We don't have the information you do, or the context, or the issue.  If you don't put that in, there's no way for us to help you.  Help us help you.

Comment: Regarding the politeness point, closing questions is not impolite. Nor voting. Those are tools that the community uses to curate and moderate the site. It's not meant as a personal affront, it's just that five different users thought your question wasn't answerable or useful in that state. Closing is done this way to minimize friction and unnecessary conflict. You are supposed to react to the closure impersonally, as the system telling you "you need to improve your post". Feeling offended because you weren't treated politely is not productive.

Comment: Regarding the additional votes your question is getting now, please read on the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). Many users will refrain from voting on posts linked from meta, but not all of them will.

Comment: Also note: effort does matter. If you start with multiple typing errors in the title, users will be less likely to put in the effort to write up a comment explaining why they vote to close, because why should they put in effort if you haven't taken the effort to proofread your post or run it through a spell checker. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7296893) (though that talks about research, similarly we expect effort be put into making your post clear and readable)

Comment: I'm sorry for the (several) typos, surely depending on stress and being non English speaker. Yet I find awkward that this answer aimed at understanding what was wrong received so many downvotes... isn't it correct that I want to understand? if the sentence "A comment would have been much more correct as a first action." is the problem, let me state I mean that would have given me the possibility to improve, while closing didn't.

Answer (score 17):

Let's get a few things straight:

> It's not even a very strange question so I really cannot understand. I
>   personally consider very impolite this way of doing.
>
> A comment would have been much more correct as a first action.

Closing the question is the *only* way we can ensure that we have the undivided attention of the OP to fix and address deficiencies in their question.  It also safeguards the question from incomplete or otherwise poor answers.  Comments don't do that.

To the actual question - the big thing here is that you may be missing an attempt at what you're trying to solve. You've described the problem and laid out some requirements, but there's no actual attempt here.  So, my recommendation would be to make *some* headway into solving this problem and coming back to us when you're stuck.

Note that we don't quantify "I don't know what to do" in the same light as "I'm stuck", since the former implies that *nothing* has been done (and would lead itself to open-ended, discussion-type answers).

Comment: Sure! I don't know what "luminosity" css filter really does, so it's very difficult to implement it with any instrument. That's part of the question. Stackoverflow it's pleanty of questions of developers that ask how to do things w/o explaining what they did/ As far as the question is interesting it's ok and accepted.

Comment: After being put on hold I added some information (that I personally consider useless) on why I need it. But that didn't change, the answer was closed leaving me with no clue on what was wrong. As the comment of Xufox demonstrates what I asked was enough to understand the problem. For those who know the matter...